# Should I use subjunctive mood when I'm writing a document?

Tags: subjunctives

> the subjunctive mood is used to explore conditional or **imaginary**
>   **situations**.

I want to write,

> When it **is** processing task-A, it would frequently use the XXX
>   resource.

It seems like an imaginary situation, so should it be

> When it **was** processing task-A, it would frequently use the XXX
>   resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of your examples use the subjunctive. The difference is a simple matter of tense. The first is present continuous, the second is past continuous.

There is nothing imaginary about the situation. But the second part of the sentence uses the past tense so it is reasonable for the "when" clause to also be past tense: "When it was..." looks better.

An imaginary situation with a subjunctive could start:

> If it were processing...

But in modern English the subjunctive is strictly optional, and exactly the same meaning and sense of an imaginary situation could be

> If it was processing